# Find the eigenvalues of $A$. $A^2 = 1$ and $A\ne\pm1$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, with $A^2 = 1$ and $A\ne\pm1$

Show that the only eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: Do you mean that $A^2 = I$ and $A \not= \pm I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix of size $n \times n$?

Answer (score 5):

Hint: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, what can you say about eigenvalues of $A^2$?

Answer (score 3):

We have that:

$$\mathbf{A}^{2} = \mathbf{I} \implies \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{A}^{-1}$$

But we know that if the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ are $\lambda_{1},\dots,\lambda_{n}$, then the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ are $\lambda_{1}^{-1},\dots,\lambda_{n}^{-1}$, but if:

$$\lambda_{i}=\lambda_{i}^{-1} \qquad \forall i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$$

Then:

$$\lambda_{i}=\pm 1 \qquad \forall i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
Av = \lambda v \Rightarrow A^2v = \lambda Av = v
$$

So
$$
\lambda Av = v \Rightarrow \lambda \lambda v = \lambda ^2v = v
$$

This shows $\lambda = 1$ or $\lambda = -1$.